# mawk syntax appropriate >1000 field file for counting non-numeric data column-wise?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, gnu-parallel

The following silly hard-coding of what ought to be some kind of loop or parallel construct, works nominally, but it is poor mawk syntax.  My good mawk syntax attempts have all failed, using for loops in mawk (not shown) and gnu parallel (not shown).

It really needs to read the CSV file from disk just 1 time, not one time per column, because I have a really big CSV file (millions of rows, thousands of columns). My original code worked fine-ish (not shown) but it read the whole disk file again for every column and it was taking hours and I killed it after realizing what was happening. I have a fast solid state disk using a GPU connector slot so disk reads are blazing fast on this device. Thus CPU is the bottleneck here. Code sillyness is even more of a bottleneck if I have to hard-code 4000 lines of basically the same statements except for column number.

The code is column-wise making counts of non-numeric values.  I need some looping (for-loop) or parallel (preferred) because while the following works correctly on 2 columns, it is not a scalable way to write mawk code for thousands of columns.

```
tail -n +1 pht.csv | awk -F"," '(($1+0 != $1) && ($1!="")){cnt1++}; (($2+0 != $2) && ($2!="")){cnt2++} END{print cnt1+0; print cnt2+0}'
2
1
```

How can the "column 1 processing; column 2 processing;" duplicate code be reduced?  How can looping be introduced? How can gnu parallel be introduced?   Thanks much.  New to awk, I am. Not new to other languages.

I keep expecting some clever combo of one or more of the following bash commands is going to solve this handily, but here I am many hours later with nothing to show. I come with open hands. Alms for the code-poor?

- seq 1 2 ( >>2 for real life CSV file)
- tail (to skip the header or not as needed)
- mawk (nice-ish row-wise CSV file processing, with that handy syntax I showed you in my demo for finding non-numerics easily in a supposedly all-numeric CSV datafile of jumbo dimensions)
- tr (removes newline which is handy for transpose-ish operations)
- cut (to grab a column at a time)
- parallel (fast is good, and I have mucho cores needing something to work on, and phat RAM)

Sorry, I am absolutely required to not use CSV specific libraries like python pandas or R dataframes. My hands are tied here. Sorry. Thank you for being so cool about it. I can only use bash command lines in this case.

My mawk can handle 32000+ columns so NF is not a problem here, unlike some other awk I've seen. I have less than 32000 columns (but not by that much).

Datafile pht.csv contains the following 3x2 dataset:

```
cat pht.csv
8,T1,
T13,3,T1
T13,,-6.350818276405334473e-01
```

Comment: Datamash runs on the bash command line. Is that acceptable? https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/

Comment: @OleTange I will check into it. THanks again!   Hey I really want to get gnu parallel to replace the for loop in my later answer here.  Is it possible? Big Thanks to you for being so supportive the other day and what seems like every day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't have access to `mawk` but you can do something equivalent to this

```
awk -F, 'NR>1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/[[:alpha:]]/) a[i]++} 
         END  {for(i=1;i in a;i++) print a[i]}' file
```

shouldn't take more than few minutes even for million records.

For recognizing exponential notation regex test is not going to work and you need to revert to `$1+0!=$1` test as mentioned in the comments.  Note that you don't have to check null string separately.

Comment: The core thing here is "use an array, Luke".  You might want to spell that out.

Comment: That will fail for exponential numbers. The test for non-numeric values is `$1+0 != $1`. Yes, I know the tiny sample input the OP posted doesn't have exponential numbers but he tells us his input file is quite a bit larger than that and he's using that test so maybe....

Comment: @Ed Morton Yes you are correct. Exponential notation numbers are a test case that is useful and helpful here.  Thanks

Comment: @karakfa I like your "not alpha" idea.  I hope it works as it's nice and clear.

Comment: @tripleee You are right on. Dynamic arrays are indeed what I found worked for me before checking back in here today.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes you are correct. Exponential notation numbers are a test case that is useful and helpful here. Thanks

Comment: @EdMorton  I edited the test data to put an exponential number into it. Thanks again

Comment: 2 2 2 was output by this answer on the admittedly updated dataset, which is incorrect. Correct is 2 1 1.  For this test I ran the version of your answer including the $1+0!=$1. The nulls in the updated data are the reason and I don't expect you to be a mind-reading future-teller so your solution is good at any rate.  However my solution omits the explicit conditional, which is nice, so there's that. Anyway yours is nearly the same as mine and is therefore good and accurate if I put that null string check in, I am certain. @EdMorton had the wrong output but code still helpful. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions so far parallelize. Let's change that.

Assume you have a solution that works in serial and can read from a pipe:

```
doit() {
    # This solution gives 5-10 MB/s depending on system
    # Changed so it now also treats '' as zero
    perl -F, -ane 'for(0..$#F) { 
        # Perl has no beautiful way of matching scientific notation
        $s[$_] += $F[$_] !~ /^-?\d*(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?$/m
    }
    END { $" = ","; print "@s\n" }';
}
export -f doit

doit() {
    # Somewhat faster - but regards empty fields as zero
    mawk -F"," '{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { cnt[i]+=(($i+0)!=$i) && ($i!="") } 
    }
    END { for(i=1;i<NF;i++) printf cnt[i]","; print cnt[NF] }';
}
export -f doit
```

To parallelize this we need to split the big file into chunks and pass each chunk to the serial solution:

```
# This will spawn a process for each core
parallel --pipe-part -a pht.csv --block -1 doit > blocksums
```

(You need version 20161222 or later to use '--block -1').

To deal with the header we compute result of the header, but we negate the result:

```
head -n1 pht.csv | doit | perl -pe 's/(^|,)/$1-/g' > headersum
```

Now we can simply sum up the headersum and the blocksums:

```
cat headersum blocksums |
  perl -F, -ane 'for(0..$#F) { $s[$_] += $F[$_] }
                 END { $" = ",";print "@s\n" }'
```

Or if you prefer the output line by line:

```
cat headersum blocksums |
  perl -F, -ane 'for(0..$#F) { $s[$_] += $F[$_] }
                 END { $" = "\n";print "@s\n" }'
```

Comment: Oh nuts I'm running GNU parallel 20141022.  It's time to upgrade mine! Hopefully a plain old tar and make will get the new parallel running soon at this location...

Comment: The [:alpha:] does not work due to missing data intentionally added to the test dataset since you last looked at it, as I determined on the other answer.  I also added exponential number too.  Nevertheless I will try to incorporate your code here plus these changes myself and report back, after also installing a new gnu parallel haha.

Comment: I downloaded latest parallel, ran the tar and make per README. Old version (parallel -V reports a 2014 version) still runs, oddly.  But this runs the new version: /usr/local/bin/sem -V  .... GNU parallel 20170222.  How do I fix it?  How to cause parallel cmd to run that sem cmd? When I do update-alternatives it does not know what the parallel cmd is. I have hard time finding where on my path your parallel program was installed to....

Comment: ok parallel -V works now just fine after I closed terminal and opened a new terminal. haha

Comment: Output is incorrect: 1,2,0   Correct is: 2 1 1 (on different lines). This was using code in :alpha: block changed to:  { $s[$_] += ($F[$_] + 0) =~ $F[$_] }  If there is some way to fix so it works, it would be nice to get it working! Thank you!

Comment: Your new code runs great on test. Running biggie file for speed test, please wait...

Comment: Wrong result is produced by doit #1 on real data: particularly, 509885 non-numerics are reported by doit #1 on real data's column 2. Eyeballing this 1.1 million row column manually, I can see directly there are actually no nonnumerics at all, just plenty of missing data and decimal values.  The simple sequential awk program I wrote reports 0 non-numerics in column 2, which is correct. Something seems wrong in your perl code and my tiny test dataset is too weak to find it, sadly.  Further: doit #2 produces wrong result 2 0 1 on test dataset, and no further execution of doit #2 is warranted.

Comment: Then you need to show the expected output of the pht.csv example in your question. Both versions give '2,1,1' on pht.csv on my system (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: Yes of course. OK I developed test data: added a new column. I will post up in a minute. Also made minor code improvements for correctness. The header counts was the problem here -- easy fix once understood.  25x parallel speedup seen on 32 virtual / 16 physical core shared memory host:  (32x60) seconds sequential time, 74 sec parallel time. AWESOME!  It works BLAZING FAST!    Yours is slightly more complex code which I could not have written myself (yet). Whereas sequential I did write myself. GREAT STUFF. Thank you Mr. Tange.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -v RS='[\n,]' '($1+0) != $1' file | sort | uniq -c
      1 T1
      2 T13
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and should run in seconds for an input file like you describe. If you don't have GNU awk you could do:

```
$ tr ',' $'\n' < file | awk '($1+0) != $1' | sort | uniq -c
      1 T1
      2 T13
```

I'm avoiding the approach of using `,` as a FS since then you'd have to use `$i` in a loop which would cause awk to do field splitting for every input line which adds on time but you could try it:

```
$ awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (($i+0) != $i) print $i}' file | sort | uniq -c
      1 T1
      2 T13
```

You could do the unique counting all in awk with an array indexed by the non-numeric values but then you potentially have to store a lot of data in memory (unlike with `sort` which uses temp swap files as necessary) so YMMV with that approach.

Comment: Actually the required output is 2 1 1 on the new test data I added today, one value per line of output.  That would be 2 1 on the old test data you used if I recall.  These are counts of non-numeric data appearing in the columns of the CSV file.

Comment: Despite the required output being 2 1 in this case, the unique values output by your original code is also going to be useful in some other scenarios than the required output. So thanks for showing it here.

Comment: I didn't test against new data, I tested against your original data. Obviously you can pipe the output in my answer to `awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR?1?OFS:""), $1} END{print ""}'` or any number of other scripts if you want to only get the numbers output.

Comment: Best I can make out, this is what you are suggesting I run:  $ awk -v RS='[\n,]' '($1+0) != $1' pht.csv | sort | uniq -c | awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR?1?OFS:""), $1} END{print ""}'
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )

Comment: Typo: `NR>1` not `NR?1`. Google ternary expression for the common syntax.

Comment: Counts of unique anything cannot result in the required output.

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Let's assume I just don't understand your requirements and hopefully someone else does - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it independently. What finally did it for me was the dynamic variable creation examples at the following URL.  http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24

Here is the solution I developed.  Note: I have added another column with some missing data for a more complete unit test.  Mine is not necessarily the best solution, which is TBD.  It works correctly on the small csv shown is all I know at the moment. The best solution will also need to run really fast on a 40 GB csv file (not shown haha).

```
$ cat pht.csv
8,T1,
T13,3,T1
T13,,0

$ tail -n +1 pht.csv | awk -F"," '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { cnt[i]+=(($i+0)!=$i) && ($i!="") } } END { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print cnt[i] }'
2
1
1
```

ps. Honestly I am not satisfied with my own answer. They say that premature optimization is the root of all evil.  Well that maxim does *not* apply here. I really, really want gnu parallel in there, instead of the for-loop if possible, because I have a need for speed.

Comment: sys 0m46.632s for this solution's time. Other solutions' results soon...

Comment: I wrote the CUS FAQ you reference and I can't imagine how it's applicable here.

Comment: @EdMorton What finally did it for me was the dynamic variable creation examples in awk.  This was my first time ever seeing this syntax.

Comment: @EdMorton  Thank you for writing the CUS FAQ!

Comment: @tripleee I do not appreciate your destructive activity on my efforts here. Such destructiveness is what ultimately drives people away from this web site.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson Pardon? Removing commentary which does not explain the answer is part of normal clean-up activity here. The intent is certainly not to be destructive, but your commentary on how you plan to evaluate the other answers here would belong as a comment.  It's all there in the edit history, where you could rollback with a single click if you wanted to (but better to raise a question on [meta] first if you actually want to do that). In any event, sorry if you perceived this editing to be destructive - my intent is to keep the site clean and straightforward, esp. for new visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Final note: Below I am sharing performance timings of sequential and parallel versions, and best available unit test dataset. Special thank you to Ole Tange for big help developing code to use his nice gnu parallel command in this application.

Unit test datafile, final version:

```
$ cat pht2.csv
COLA99,COLB,COLC,COLD
8,T1,,T1
T13,3,T1,0.03
T13,,-6.350818276405334473e-01,-0.036
```

Timing on big data (not shown) for sequential version of column-wise non-numeric counts:

```
ga@ga-HP-Z820:/mnt/fastssd$ time tail -n +2 train_all.csv | awk -F"," '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ cnt[i]+=(($i+0)!=$i) && ($i!="") } } END { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print cnt[i] }' > /dev/null

real    35m37.121s
```

Timing on big data for parallel version of column-wise non-numeric counts:

```
# Correctness - 2 1 1 1 is the correct output.
#
# pht2.csv: 2 1 1 1 :GOOD
# train_all.csv: 
# real  1m14.253s
doit1() {
    perl -F, -ane 'for(0..$#F) { 
        # Perl has no beautiful way of matching scientific notation
        $s[$_] += $F[$_] !~ /^-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?$/m
    }
    END { $" = ","; print "@s\n" }';
}

# pht2.csv: 2 1 1 1 :GOOD
# train_all.csv: 
# real  1m59.960s
doit2() {        
    mawk -F"," '{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { cnt[i]+=(($i+0)!=$i) && ($i!="") } 
    }
    END { for(i=1;i<NF;i++) printf cnt[i]","; print cnt[NF] }';
}

export -f doit1
parallel --pipe-part -a "$fn" --block -1 doit1 > blocksums
if [ $csvheader -eq 1 ] 
then
    head -n1 "$fn" | doit1 | perl -pe 's/(^|,)/$1-/g' > headersum
    cat headersum blocksums | perl -F, -ane 'for(0..$#F) { $s[$_] += $F[$_] } END { $" = "\n";print "@s\n" }' > "$outfile"
else
    cat blocksums | perl -F, -ane 'for(0..$#F) { $s[$_] += $F[$_] } END { $" = "\n";print "@s\n" }' > "$outfile"
fi
```

NEW: Here is the ROW-wise (not column-wise) counts in sequential code:

```
tail -n +2 train_all.csv | awk -F"," '{ cnt=0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ cnt+=(($i+0)!=$i) && ($i!="") } print cnt; }' > train_all_cnt_nonnumerics_rowwwise.out.txt
```

Context:  Project is **machine learning**. This is part of a data exploration. **~25x parallel speedup** seen on Dual Xeon 32 virtual / 16 physical core shared memory host using Samsung 950 Pro SSD storage: (32x60) seconds sequential time, 74 sec parallel time. AWESOME!